# Power series expansion for $ f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2} $

Tags: calculus, power-series

I struggle to find the power series expansion of

$$
 f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}
$$

I stopped here
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{(-1)^n*(x+1)^{2n}}
$$
but I can't seem to find how to get to $ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{ a_n x^{n}} $. is it even possible ?

Comment: The power series expansion centered at which point?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would probably write $f(x) = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{1}{1-\omega x} + \frac{1}{1 - \bar\omega x} \right)$ where $\omega = \frac{1+i}{2}$, so $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(n\pi/4) / 2^{n/2} \cdot x^n$ - though the details might be off there, the approach should be sound.

Comment: Oh, or for the snake oil method: $f(x) = \frac{x^2-2x+2}{x^4+4} = (x^2-2x+2) \cdot \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1/4)^n x^{4n}$ which then has no overlaps of coefficients on $x^m$ terms.

Comment: $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{(-1)^n*(x+1)^{2n}}$ is already "a power series expansion" of $f(x)$.

Comment: My guess based on wanting to get to the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is that the OP wants a power series expansion centered at 0.

Comment: in our course, we just learned that power series are function series that takes  the form of $ f(x)=\sum{a_n x^n} $ we didn't cover where are they centered and how it affects the form so thank you all for your help

Comment: @DanielSchepler I believe your snake oil solution should be turn into the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}$$ where $a=-1-i$ and $b=-1+i$. So, using partial fraction decomposition
$$f(x)=\frac 1{a-b} \left(\frac 1{x-a}-\frac 1{x-b}\right)$$ Now, look at the series expansion
$$\frac 1{x-c}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty c^{-(n+1)}x^n$$

Apply twice, play with the complex numbers to get
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n\,x^n$$ where
$$d_n= 2^{-(n+2)} (1+i)\left((-1+i)^n-i (-1-i)^n\right)$$ which, for sure, are all real.

For sure, you can play with trigonometric functions and have
$$d_n= 2^{-\frac{n}{2}-1} \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  n}{4}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi  n}{4}\right)\right)$$ that you could still simplify.

Comment: I got $$\frac{1}{x^2+2 x+2}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } 2^{-\frac{n}{2}} x^{n-1} \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi  n}{4}\right)$$